# Retrieving old platform events using replayId as -2

Tags: platform-event, streaming-api

I have a lighting component which subscribes to a event channel `Notification__e` on load. I have used `replayId =-2` to read all the old events.

```
subscribe: function (component, event, helper) {
    const empApi = component.find('empApi');
    const channel = component.get('v.channel');
    const replayId = -2;
    const callback = function (message) {
        console.log('Event Received : ' + JSON.stringify(message));
    };

    // Subscribe to the channel and save the returned subscription object.
    empApi.subscribe(
        channel, 
        replayId, 
        $A.getCallback(callback)
    ).then(
        $A.getCallback(function (newSubscription) {
            console.log(newSubscription);
            component.set('v.subscription', newSubscription);
        })
    );
}
```

But, on reload, component either gives old events information or it errors out.
**I could not figure out why it sometimes retrieves old events and sometimes throws out error message.** Also, it is giving stored events information which were created on 6th sept but as per doc salesforce stores events for 24 hours.

### Old Events

```
Event Received : {"data":{"schema":"2-WbrEYaxZwZWJVS5I0l9Q",
"payload":{"CreatedById":"0052v00000VcpWtAAJ","Message__c":"Watch out, bear 
 spotted!","CreatedDate":"2019-09-06T09:38:56Z"},"event": 
 {"replayId":1025104}},"channel":"/event/Notification__e"}

Event Received : {"data":{"schema":"2-WbrEYaxZwZWJVS5I0l9Q","payload": 
{"CreatedById":"0052v00000VcpWtAAJ","Message__c":"Watch out, bear 
spotted!","CreatedDate":"2019-09-06T09:39:04Z"},"event": 
{"replayId":1025105}},"channel":"/event/Notification__e"}

Event Received : {"data":{"schema":"2-WbrEYaxZwZWJVS5I0l9Q","payload": 
{"CreatedById":"0052v00000VcpWtAAJ","Message__c":"Watch out, bear 
spotted!","CreatedDate":"2019-09-10T14:10:57Z"},"event": 
{"replayId":1025953}},"channel":"/event/Notification__e"}
```

### Error Messages

> {"clientId":"5qi16wx0fqh37geo1sytv4xvwp0qk","advice":{"interval":0,"reconnect":"none"},"channel":"/meta/connect","id":"3","error":"403::Unknown
>   client","successful":false}
>
> {"clientId":"5qjfzyexvvngf1lly1u9ozgp6y5","advice":{"interval":0,"reconnect":"none"},"channel":"/meta/connect","id":"8","error":"403::Unknown
>   client","successful":false}
>
> {"id":"2","successful":false,"channel":"/meta/subscribe","failure":{"reason":"Request
>   2 of transport long-polling exceeded 10000 ms max network
>   delay","httpCode":0,"connectionType":"unknown","transport":{},"message":{"id":"2","channel":"/meta/subscribe","subscription":"/event/Notification__e","clientId":"5qi16wx0fqh37geo1sytv4xvwp0qk","ext":{"replay":{"/event/Notification__e":-2}}}},"subscription":"/event/Notification__e"}
>
> {"id":"6","successful":false,"channel":"/meta/subscribe","failure":{"reason":"Request
>   9 of transport long-polling exceeded 10000 ms max network
>   delay","httpCode":0,"connectionType":"unknown","transport":{},"message":{"id":"6","channel":"/meta/subscribe","subscription":"/s/notifications/notification","clientId":"5qjfzyexvvngf1lly1u9ozgp6y5","ext":{"replay":{"/s/notifications/notification":-1}}}},"subscription":"/s/notifications/notification"}

Comment: Formatting tips: Horizontal scroll bars are bad, when pasting code format it in a way to where there is no horizontal scroll bars if possible. Errors go in quotes (quotes don't have scroll bars). Code formatting is only for code, for headings use "##" in front of your text. For emphasized, non-code, text, use bold.

Comment: Thanks! Helpful tips.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're having network connection problems. Please contact your IT department or Internet Provider.

[Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_streaming.meta/api_streaming/streaming_error_codes.htm):

> 403::Unknown Client: The server deleted the client CometD session due to a timeout, which can be caused by a network failure. The client must perform a new handshake and reconnect.

Both errors suggest that your connection is dropping out for relatively extended periods of time.

Also, as of API 37.0, [messages may be stored up to 72 hours](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_streaming.meta/api_streaming/using_streaming_api_durability.htm).

Comment: Thanks! I can see this information in link that you have shared but it is missing from the trailhead module. It still says events are stored till 24 hours which caused confusion with the retrieved result.

Comment: @devforce It depends on the type of event you're using.